# OMP update vector issue

Tags: fortran, openmp

I have the following snippet of code

```
!$OMP PARALLEL PRIVATE(i)
  do i = inode1,inode2
     if (mod(CEILING(Rat(1,i)*checkerDivider),2).ne.mod(CEILING(Rat(2,i)*checkerDivider),2)) then
           H0(i) = H0(i)
     else
           H0(i) = H0(i) + onsiteShift
     endif
  end do
  !$OMP END PARALLEL
```

onsiteShift equals 0.02, and H0(i) is equal to 0. For this example, I work on 16 processors. Whenever I enter the `else` clause, it should set the values of H0(i) to 0.02, obviously. However, in this case, I end up with random values between 0 and 0.32 (with steps of 0.02). Clearly, I enter the clause more than once for a same value of `i`. I tried using `!$OMP ATOMIC UPDATE` as well, but then I end up with a value of exactly of 0.32 (= 16*0.02...).

Also, I thought that by using a temporary `H0_temp` variable, I would avoid having different threads having this racing condition problem.

```
!$OMP PARALLEL PRIVATE(i, H0_temp)
  do i = inode1,inode2
     H0_temp = H0(i)
     if (mod(CEILING(Rat(1,i)*checkerDivider),2).ne.mod(CEILING(Rat(2,i)*checkerDivider),2)) then
           H0_temp = H0_temp
     else
           H0_temp = H0_temp + onsiteShift
     endif
     H0(i) = H0_temp
  end do
  !$OMP END PARALLEL
```

Still, it doesn't work. I have also tried something along the lines of a reduction...

Basically, how to change the value of H0(i) using OMP? The end result of H0 should be either 0 or 0.02. No other value. If I use only one processor there is no problem...

My second question, how big an impact can such problem have on my previous calculations. I only noted the problem for this case, but I suspect I might have the same problem for many of my other loops. Or does it somehow (hopefully) become less a problem when the value of `inode2` is very large (around 20 million for my production runs)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just forgot the `DO` in

```
!$OMP PARALLEL DO PRIVATE(i)
```

Therefore no worksharing took place and all threads were doing complete loops.

Regarding the additional question: yes, it is a serious problem and you must fix it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Like most errors, they look stupid once one has located them. I'm indeed afraid I'll have to do most of my production runs again... And btw, you were right for reminding me to post a minimal working code, I acted in a hurry at the airport. Anyhow, things are solved now.

Comment: In the end, seems like the other loops are ok. I'm building on someone else's code, and he actually used a different approach for the worksharing to take place... the values of inode1 and inode2 are THREADPRIVATE variables which are different for each thread. But for this specific instance indeed, they were not. Not that it matters for my question or your answer, but for sake of completeness.